# ApexCharts skipping X axis ticks

Tags: apexcharts

I would like to present a bar chart using Apex Charts.

The graphs shows some items, the more items the longer you can do some stuff. The items are presented in the Y axis. The X axis should represent months in a year, therefore I want it to be fixed between 0 and 12.

With the following options, it skips some numbers in the x axis:

```
var options = {
        series: [{ data: [3,4,6,7,8.5] }],
        chart: { type: 'bar', height: 250 },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: { borderRadius: 4, horizontal: true }
        },
        dataLabels: { enabled: false },
        xaxis: {
            categories: [2,3,5,6,7],
            min: 0,
            max: 12,
        },
        yaxis: {
            labels: { formatter: function (val) { return val + ' items'; } },
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart title', floating: true, align: 'center',
            style: { color: '#444' }
          }
      };
```

[image: Note how the 9 is omitted]

If I omit the min/max in the xaxis, it works fine but the 12 months are not fixed as required.

In the example the 9 is skipped, but the actual bars are scalled correctly

I am loading the library using de direct script include:
 `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>`

Here you can find the official example/docs: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/basic/

Have I overlooked something? Or is it a bug?

Setting `tickAmount` to 12 seems to fix the problem, but I does not behave correctly with other numbers. (if I use 13 then it inserts two 6 tiks instead of inserting decimals)